# Tizen SDK installation - the installmanager.conf or Package file cannot be saved

Tags: sdk, installation, tizen

Trying to install the Tizen SDK on Mac OS X Mavericks thru the Package Server and thru the SDK image (zip). In both instances it gives the error "the installmanager.conf or Package file cannot be saved" error towards the end. I tried doing the 'chown -R $USER ~/tmp' and 'sudo chown -R $USER ~/tmp' but it did not work.

Is there a work around or am I doing something wrong?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Guess, I found the solution: if the installation folder does not have permission then it throws weird errors. Install the sdk on a folder which has full permissions for the user.

Comment: feel free to accept your own answer if it solves problem you posted. And thanks for sharing solution!